# array_unique does not re-sort the array

Tags: php

I have an array which is like this:

```
$x = array("15","15","18","18","18","18","12","12");
```

then I want to get the unique values, which results in an array with unique values but with keys not reordered. What should I do? I want to avoid putting it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Suggestion is to use

```
array_values(array_unique($x));
```

In this way, your array is first cleaned of the duplicate values, and then this array is returned to the function and finally the array values returns a re-ordered array of the filtered array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) to re-index the array:

```
$x = array("15","15","18","18","18","18","12","12");
$unique = array_values(array_unique($x));
print_r($unique);
```

You can also use the [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort) function, as mario suggested in the comments:

```
$unique = array_unique($x);
sort($unique);
print_r($unique);
```

Both of these will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 18
    [2] => 12
)
```