# array_unique does not sort a simple string array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-unique

According to the PHP documentation, [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) removes duplicate values and sorts the values treated as string at first.

When you take the following snippet in mind:

```
// define a simple array of strings, unordered
$brands = [ "BMW", "Audi", "BMW", "Chrysler", "Daewoo"];

// distinct the values, and sort them
echo array_unique($brands, SORT_STRING);
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
expected: {"0":"Audi","1":"BMW","3":"Chrysler","4":"Daewoo"}
actual  : {"0":"BMW","1":"Audi","3":"Chrysler","4":"Daewoo"}
```

The question is: why doesn't array_unique sort these values? Changing the sort_flags parameter to any of the four alternatives, or leaving it empty, has no effect either.

According to other SO questions, like ["Why does array unique sort the values"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348664/why-does-array-unique-sort-the-values) I'm probably missing something obvious here. Also, using `array_values(array_unique($brands))`, as stated as an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618946/array-unique-does-not-re-sort-the-array) doesn't seem to work either.

**Update**: As stated in the useful comments and answers, the *sort_flags* parameter is actually an inner compare behavior, or equality operator, sort of speak.

Comment: `array_unique` does **not sort** array elements. It just removes duplicate values from array. The manual is only mentioning the _sorts_ word regarding to internal (temporary) array processing. It doesn't mean real array sorting

Comment: So, actually 'sort_flag' should really be interpreted as 'compare_behaviour'? If so, the naming convention and the forementioned posts confused me on this part.

Comment: Also don't use `echo` with non-scalar values.

Answer (score 3):

In manual they mean that values group by value and first key taken for eacj duplicated value.

you need something like this

```
$brands = array_unique($brands);
sort($brands);
```

SORT_STRING - is default

Comment: You cannot call `sort` this way, BTW.

Comment: `sort` doesn't return the sorted array, it returns a boolean indicating whether it was successful. It relies on the array being passed by reference, which I don't think is compatible with using the result of a function.

Comment: this works though: `$brands = array_unique($brands); sort($brands);`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation simply specifies how the algorithm is working internally to achieve its purpose. Why and how is well explained in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348664/why-does-array-unique-sort-the-values). It does not say that the returned result will be sorted as well. Sorting is outside the scope of this function and probably actually undesired most of the time.

For completeness, this is how'd you unique (is that a verb?) *and* sort the array:

```
$array = array_unique($array);
sort($array);
```

Comment: There's no harm in adding a quick two line example to make your answer complete.

Comment: @Tom An example of what exactly?

Comment: An example of how you would obtain the sorted, unique values of an array.

Comment: I thought I was just answering the question *why `array_unique` _doesn't_ sort*. I'd think the OP could do it manually if they wanted...?! :)

Comment: Sure, it's just that currently the only answer suggesting how you might actually go about doing it is wrong!

Comment: For the record, it's not a verb :)

Comment: _BTW_: It would be better to apply `sort` first, then `array_unique`. This allow to prevent "double" sorting because in this case `array_unique` will have already sorted array and won't perform internal sorting.